# Python / Pandas - Filtering rows according to criteria

Tags: python, pandas

I have this dataframe:

```
bal:

             year   id   unit period  Ativo Circulante  Ativo Não-Circulante  \
business_id                                                                    
9564         2012  302  dsada  anual        5964168.52           10976013.70   
9564         2011  303  dsada  anual        5774707.15           10867868.13   
2361         2013  304  dsada  anual        3652575.31            6608468.52   
2361         2012  305  dsada  anual         321076.15            6027066.03   
2369         2013  306  dsada  anual        3858137.49            9733126.02   
2369         2012  307  dsada  anual         351373.66            9402830.89   
8104         2012  308  dsada  anual        3503226.02            6267307.01 
...
```

I want it to filter it in a way that each index only have the data for its last year. It would look like this:

```
             year   id   unit period  Ativo Circulante  Ativo Não-Circulante  \
business_id                                                                    
9564         2012  302  dsada  anual        5964168.52           10976013.70   
2361         2013  304  dsada  anual        3652575.31            6608468.52   
2369         2013  306  dsada  anual        3858137.49            9733126.02   
8104         2012  308  dsada  anual        3503226.02            6267307.01 
...
```

How could I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do it in Pandas precisely as you describe it in English:

```
bal.sort_values('year').groupby(bal.index).last()

#             year   id   unit period  Ativo_Circulante  Ativo_Não-Circulante
#business_id                                                                 
#2361         2012  307  dsada  anual         351373.66            9402830.89
#2369         2013  304  dsada  anual        3652575.31            6608468.52
#8104         2013  306  dsada  anual        3858137.49            9733126.02
#9564         2012  302  dsada  anual        5964168.52           10976013.70
```

Answer (score 1):

Or you can do boolean indexing by not keeping the first duplicate i.e

```
bal[~bal.index.duplicated(keep='first')]
```

Output:

```
             year   id   unit period  Ativo_Circulante  Ativo_Não-Circulante
business_id                                                                 
9564         2012  302  dsada  anual  5964168.52        10976013.70         
2361         2013  304  dsada  anual  3652575.31        6608468.52          
2369         2013  306  dsada  anual  3858137.49        9733126.02          
8104         2012  308  dsada  anual  3503226.02        6267307.01          
In [576]:
```

Comment: There may be more than one duplicate. Also, the DataFrame must first be sorted by year, anyway. If it is not, any row may be the first one.